Дискорд бот не может получить логи сообщений
Есть такой код:
client = discord.Client(intents=(discord.Intents.all()))

async def getMessages():
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)

    messages = await channel.history()

client.run(**TOKEN**)  

Однако при запуске и вызове этой функции, бот зависает. Как можно пофиксить это?

Какую версию библиотеки discord.py вы используете? Выглядит так, что Вы используете очень старую версию, либо неудачно скопировали чей-то код в интернете.

Читайте документацию, там всё написано.

discord.TextChannel.history

messages = [message async for message in channel.history(limit=123)]

